# Vhost configuration on apache

Tags: apache, configuration, subdomain, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I've a problem with my apache server.

I just did a fresh install(debian 6.0).

I created two config files: mysite.com and dev.mysite.com in /etc/apache2/sites-available, I enabled them with the a2ensite command, and I reloaded the server(/etc/init.d/apache2 reload)

I modified my host file to redirect the two requests to my server. I've no problem when trying to reach mysite.com, but when I try to access dev.mysite.com I get the content of mysite.com.

Here are my config files:

part of apache2.conf

```
# Include ports listing
Include ports.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/*
```

the ports.conf file

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

the sites-available/mysite.com  file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin web@mydomain.com
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias mysites.com
        ServerAlias www.mysites.com
        ServerAlias mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /media/Data/www/mysiteCom
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /media/Data/www/mysiteCom>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_mysiteCom
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_mysiteCom combined
        ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

my sites-available/dev.mysite.com file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin web@mydomain.com
        ServerName dev.mysite.com
        ServerAlias dev.mysites.com
        DocumentRoot /media/Data/www/devMysiteCom
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /media/Data/www/devMysiteCom>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_devMysiteCom
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_devMysiteCom combined
        ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea of what I did wrong?

Comment: this helped me in fact to set up my vhosts properly. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my error.

In facts, it seems to be mandatory to mention which port will be accessed, so I had to set it in the VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```